# Crash Log - Can't find crash

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, crash

I am getting the following crash log from a tester running my application.

```
Incident Identifier: 6E2A5626-7366-4CDE-AEB2-0A9302FAED33
CrashReporter Key:   b60265c86e67319d09e467ba61230f5d8cb62f41
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         MyApplication [12798]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/364708D2-EC63-4AA5-AF06-F9A1658BAFE2/MyApplication.app/MyApplication
Identifier:      MyApplication
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-05-06 11:53:47.852 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x354ee88f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36915259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3544623d -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 165
3   MyApplication                   0x00018ad9 -[iPhoneNewsViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (iPhoneNewsViewController.m:458)
4   UIKit                           0x3256d0a3 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 547
5   UIKit                           0x3256c181 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1077
6   UIKit                           0x3256b90b -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207
7   UIKit                           0x325100df -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 183
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3544d1fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 43
9   QuartzCore                      0x36fd8aa5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 217
10  QuartzCore                      0x36fd86bd CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 217
11  QuartzCore                      0x36fdc843 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 227
12  QuartzCore                      0x36fdc57f CA::Transaction::commit() + 315
13  QuartzCore                      0x36fd44b9 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 57
14  CoreFoundation                  0x354c2b1b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
15  CoreFoundation                  0x354c0d57 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 259
16  CoreFoundation                  0x354c10b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 761
17  CoreFoundation                  0x354444a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3544436d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
19  GraphicsServices                0x36740439 GSEventRunModal + 137
20  UIKit                           0x3253ae7d UIApplicationMain + 1081
21  MyApplication                   0x00015d9b main (main.m:16)
22  MyApplication                   0x00015d34 0x14000 + 7476


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352e232c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x371de208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x371d7298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30ea3f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30ea1346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36915350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30ea13be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30ea144a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30ea281e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x369152a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35444506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35444366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices                0x36740432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                           0x3253ae76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  MyApplication                   0x00015d94 main (main.m:16)
15  MyApplication                   0x00015d2c 0x14000 + 7468

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352d23a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3151fea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3151fbc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352e2cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37199f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37199cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352e2cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37199f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37199cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352d2004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352d21fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x354c23ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x354c1124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3544449e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35444366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x372c70f0 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3719f72e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3719f5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352d2004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352d21fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x354c23ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x354c1124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3544449e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35444366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   CFNetwork                       0x33f20e14 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 340
7   Foundation                      0x313104a6 +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 242
8   Foundation                      0x31365312 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:] + 294
9   MyApplication                   0x00017510 -[iPhoneNewsViewController getNewsFeed] (iPhoneNewsViewController.m:207)
10  Foundation                      0x31310a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
11  Foundation                      0x313a458a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3719f72e _pthread_start + 314
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3719f5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352d2004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352d21fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x354c23ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x354c1124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3544449e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35444366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x31310bb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x31310a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x313a458a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3719f72e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3719f5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352e2cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37199f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37199cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352e2cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37199f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37199cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352e2570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x354c663a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3719f72e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3719f5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3fbead98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fe12a68
    r8: 0x328fb38b    r9: 0x30ea4a4a     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x328ec3e0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe12a5c      lr: 0x371de20f      pc: 0x352e232c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
   0x14000 -    0xabfff +MyApplication armv7  <1d6e8c75a32f3bb89eac5790a98d8eb4> /var/mobile/Applications/364708D2-EC63-4AA5-AF06-F9A1658BAFE2/MyApplication.app/MyApplication
0x2fe13000 - 0x2fe34fff  dyld armv7  <4a817f3e0def30d5ae2032157d889c1d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3075d000 - 0x30761fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30762000 - 0x30762fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x307c2000 - 0x30d06fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x30d07000 - 0x30d86fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x30dae000 - 0x30e86fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30e9d000 - 0x30ea4fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x30ea5000 - 0x30ef6fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30f88000 - 0x30f88fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x30f89000 - 0x30ff9fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x3106c000 - 0x31077fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31078000 - 0x31078fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3109c000 - 0x310e5fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x310e6000 - 0x310e9fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x311aa000 - 0x311abfff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x311be000 - 0x311fefff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x311ff000 - 0x31200fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31219000 - 0x31238fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31239000 - 0x31271fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x31300000 - 0x3147efff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3148a000 - 0x3148bfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3148c000 - 0x314a1fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x314a2000 - 0x314c7fff  OpenCL armv7  <ec915bfc3f7633dda61b5fc87459119b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3150c000 - 0x31512fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x31513000 - 0x31529fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3152a000 - 0x31534fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x31580000 - 0x31591fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x31592000 - 0x31592fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x3166a000 - 0x316a6fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31841000 - 0x31865fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x318c5000 - 0x318c9fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x3199f000 - 0x319ddfff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31a48000 - 0x31a49fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31b47000 - 0x31b4efff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0703f561f9a038b6850d6e93bba7e5f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x31b4f000 - 0x31b50fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x31bb6000 - 0x31c00fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31e7c000 - 0x31fc1fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31fe7000 - 0x31ff6fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x320fc000 - 0x32154fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32155000 - 0x32161fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x32168000 - 0x3216efff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3216f000 - 0x32173fff  IOSurface armv7  <6ae77a40f8e93f28bc466ca93f5675d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3218a000 - 0x321adfff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3227b000 - 0x3227ffff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x32292000 - 0x3229ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32488000 - 0x32494fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x324e1000 - 0x324f2fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x32505000 - 0x32508fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x32509000 - 0x329abfff  UIKit armv7  <d72bcc68e76a3a55a963590cdcffe8cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x331d0000 - 0x331dffff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x331e0000 - 0x331eafff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x33aba000 - 0x33abefff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x33ac5000 - 0x33b95fff  WebKit armv7  <6ff2796c2f933050ac6ecdee9fc6a216> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33c71000 - 0x33cbdfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e8eb52ca5fe33c7488a33efd222e7804> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33cdf000 - 0x33d27fff  CoreMedia armv7  <eb1f503312be3c93b07b2d0d25177000> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33dcc000 - 0x33ebafff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x33ebb000 - 0x33f92fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x34108000 - 0x3422dfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x342e0000 - 0x342ecfff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x34454000 - 0x3446afff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x347ff000 - 0x34ac0fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34ac1000 - 0x34ad7fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x34af9000 - 0x34b4afff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x34b4b000 - 0x34b82fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34c31000 - 0x34c6cfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x34c8c000 - 0x34c91fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x34d6c000 - 0x34d72fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x34e6b000 - 0x34eb5fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <5e0a131bbfec305ea01f9e01f486da63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x34ee3000 - 0x34eecfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x350e8000 - 0x350fcfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <65682d21486836a3aa3e17b9461e7b3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x35140000 - 0x351b9fff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x352c7000 - 0x352cafff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x352d1000 - 0x352e7fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7ac5560851ce3cb3981068092074b409> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x352e8000 - 0x353c7fff  RawCamera armv7  <98fb7b5042b2314b86f4be8d2881bd04> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x35435000 - 0x3554cfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x356d0000 - 0x35715fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x35861000 - 0x35896fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x35897000 - 0x359e0fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x359e8000 - 0x35a31fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x35d37000 - 0x35d3dfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x35d3e000 - 0x35efbfff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x35f26000 - 0x35f28fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35ffe000 - 0x3604cfff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x36209000 - 0x3620cfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x363c5000 - 0x365a9fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x365aa000 - 0x365aafff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x366e8000 - 0x366eefff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36733000 - 0x3673bfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3673c000 - 0x36746fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <e21a6e61bdd136b6805a9e3abe2e3d1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3675c000 - 0x36772fff  EAP8021X armv7  <fffe86a22bc434a6ae84f23bfecef9d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x36906000 - 0x3690afff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3690c000 - 0x369d2fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x369d3000 - 0x369d3fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x36b87000 - 0x36ba7fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x36d0b000 - 0x36d28fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x36d29000 - 0x36d38fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <ca5b10014b473d2eaec5c48d89ee1b54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x36d79000 - 0x36d79fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x36ea7000 - 0x36ea8fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7850befd26b630f183ee326aaadd7b34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x36f96000 - 0x36f99fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x36fd3000 - 0x370c4fff  QuartzCore armv7  <a2afbe6483683d05ad51b106f98776e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x37149000 - 0x3714afff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <66e985f3eea03ef08afb7cf4c153f76e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x37191000 - 0x3721dfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3721e000 - 0x379dcfff  WebCore armv7  <814351ff217e3425a8e532c2e2251f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x37d90000 - 0x37da9fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x37deb000 - 0x37e95fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x37eac000 - 0x37eeffff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x37f1a000 - 0x37fc7fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x38007000 - 0x3800ffff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x38012000 - 0x38017fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x380bb000 - 0x380fffff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3834e000 - 0x38350fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x3836b000 - 0x3836efff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
```

I can't find what is wrong in the log, thread 0 is crashing but I can't work out why.

The application works fine for me, but my tester - using an ad-hoc build on the same iPhone (3,1) and same iOS version.

Comment: have you tried symbolicating your crash?

Comment: thanks, i have symbolicated it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an error on line `iPhoneNewsViewController.m:458`. Looks like something wrong with `NSArray`'s `objectAtIndex:` method. Probably, you're requesting an object from empty array or object with index out-of-bounds of the array.

Comment: You were right, index that was out-of-bounds. Wasn't occurring on my device, because the loaded array was different.

Answer (score 3):

Your application is making a call into UIKit that forces a call to abort in libc. We really can't tell you much more about it until you symbolicate you crash log.

More info how that can be done is located here: 
[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Comment: thanks for that, I have replaced the crash report with it symbolicated.

Comment: can you post what is going on in your main.m around line 16. that's the origin of the error.

Answer (score 2):

you can drag and drop any crash reports into the Device Logs section of the Xcode Organiser and they will automatically by symbolicated for you. I think this works best if you built that version of the App using Build & Archive. it will tell you the line of file where the error occured,